# Wave function - BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

$$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial t^2}~=~c^2\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
BVP:
$\begin{cases}u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0,~-t<x<t,~0<t\\
u(-t,t)=b(t),~0 \leq t\\ u(t,t)=a(t),~~~~0 \leq t\end{cases}$([Boundary conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmvHY.png))

Asking for verification of the general solution

$\Phi(x,t)~=~\mathcal{F}(x-ct)+\mathcal{G}(x+ct)$([Solution to the BVP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxEPT.png))

It is just when domain is infinity or also when the domain is final (like [-1,1])?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), not embedded images. What's more important, if you don't give the context (what have you done? where have you stuck?) you will rather receive no help from MSE users (and your question will be downvoted, as it happened four times in six minutes).

Comment: thank you! i will try to use the mathjax next time.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\begin{cases}u(t,t)=a(t)\\u(-t,t)=b(t)\end{cases}$ :

$\begin{cases}F((c+1)t)+G((c-1)t)=a(t)\\F((c-1)t)+G((c+1)t)=b(t)\end{cases}$